# UIActionSheet with table view

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

HEllo,
can any one guide me for the following

- I want to add an ActionSheet with customize image.
- In ActionSheet I want to place a table view for the data.
- Two buttons(cancel & done)

Thanks....

Comment: Have you tried creating a tableview and two buttons, setting their frames and then doing addSubview on the actionsheet? You may also need to subclass it and override its drawRect method. But I think you will have more luck making your own view that animates in or out when you want. And I won't even begin to think about the HIG implications of this...

Comment: can u tell me how to display a table view as action sheet means table view should appear like action sheet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to added table in UIActionSheet just add 7 - 8 buttons in UIActionSheet and it will automatically be placed as table.

See the attached screenshot..
[image]

Comment: the screenshot is in the answer itself. see the image with "Delete , button7 , button 8, button9 .... "

Answer (score 7):

check my answer. I am using this code to display UITableView in actionsheet.

**In .h file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

**In .m file**

```
-(void)addTableViewInActionSheet
{
   UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];


    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 210)];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    [actionSheet addSubview:_tableView];

    UISegmentedControl *doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    doneButton.momentary = YES;
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    doneButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    doneButton.tintColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:doneButton];

    UISegmentedControl *cancelButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Cancel"]];
    cancelButton.momentary = YES;
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f);
    cancelButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    cancelButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:cancelButton];


    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its almost 2 years... :P

Comment: Sorry, But I have started iOS development from past 6 months and today have seen your post. So answered it. :)

Comment: No worries. It is always o.k. to answer old (already answered even) questions - your answer might come handy to any other user with a similar problem.

Comment: god I was looking for something simple like this forever

Comment: Yes, it is okay to answer old questions as the new solution might be more relevant to the current OS version and might solve recently encountered problems.

Comment: BTW @Maulik, does this conform to the iOS Human Interface Guideline?

Comment: @KarenAnne : I had used only table instead.